# Sequential deenveloping of message in several envelopes

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have an incoming message (scheme of that message i cannot control)
that is envelope of envelopes of messages.
Something like this:

```
<ns0:Companies xmlns:ns0="http://PropertyDemotionExample.Companies">
    <Header>
        <Id>Id_0</Id>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <ns0:Company xmlns:ns0="http://PropertyDemotionExample.Employees">
            <Header>
                <CompanyName>CompanyName_0</CompanyName>
                <City>City_0</City>
            </Header>
            <Body>
                <ns1:EmployeeInfo xmlns:ns1="http://PropertyDemotionExample.EmployeeInfo">
                    <Name>Name_0</Name>
                    <Id>Id_0</Id>
                    <Email>Email_0</Email>
                    <Company/>
                    <City/>
                    <Received/>
                </ns1:EmployeeInfo>
                <ns1:EmployeeInfo xmlns:ns1="http://PropertyDemotionExample.EmployeeInfo">
                    <Name>Name_1</Name>
                    <Id>Id_1</Id>
                    <Email>Email_1</Email>
                    <Company/>
                    <City/>
                    <Received/>
                </ns1:EmployeeInfo>
            </Body>
        </ns0:Company>
        <ns0:Company xmlns:ns0="http://PropertyDemotionExample.Employees">
            <Header>
                <CompanyName>CompanyName_1</CompanyName>
                <City>City_1</City>
            </Header>
            <Body>
                <ns1:EmployeeInfo xmlns:ns1="http://PropertyDemotionExample.EmployeeInfo">
                    <Name>Name_0</Name>
                    <Id>Id_0</Id>
                    <Email>Email_0</Email>
                    <Company/>
                    <City/>
                    <Received/>
                </ns1:EmployeeInfo>
                <ns1:EmployeeInfo xmlns:ns1="http://PropertyDemotionExample.EmployeeInfo">
                    <Name>Name_1</Name>
                    <Id>Id_1</Id>
                    <Email>Email_1</Email>
                    <Company/>
                    <City/>
                    <Received/>
                </ns1:EmployeeInfo>
            </Body>
        </ns0:Company>
    </Body>
</ns0:Companies>
```

I want to debatch this with receive pipelines. But when i set XPathBody property to intermediate envelope scheme, i receive error:

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline:
>   "PropertyDemotionExample.debatchpipeline, PropertyDemotionExample,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=14f78a6f44f2e0ee"
>   Source: "XML disassembler" Receive Port: "ReceiveEmployeesBatch" URI:
>   "C:\BizTalkIn\employees*.xml" Reason: The envelope structure for
>   document specification type
>   "http://PropertyDemotionExample.Employees#Company" is not valid.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your xsd so it is hard to say.
You shall have 2 schemas, one for the envelop and one for the body.

There's a walkthrough on setting up envelop schema here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546772.aspx

Check if you have missed something.

Comment: I have two envelopes over the body. Companies that envelope list of companies and Company, that envelopes list of Employee of that company. I need to use as correlation set Companies/Header/Id and Companies/Body/Company/Header/CompanyName. How can i deenvelope this and promote this properties to message context?

Comment: 1. To promote the envelop schema elements, simply create a property schema and promote your envelop schema's element (in your case, it is the Header/Id element.


2. You have 2 envelops?  you shall merge these 2 envelops into 1. I do not think xml deassembler will de-batching twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Xpath after the receiving the complete message as is. Doing Xpath at first occurence of body segment(of outer envelope) will split all internal envelopes into multiple messages which can be subscribed by other downstream processes.